# How to display a node's last saved date?

Tags: nodes, 8, forms

Drupal 8 already displays the last saved date in page edit form. I want to add a field to a node that displays it again. I am using `hook_form_alter()` and doing this in my module, but it displays the current date.

```
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
    $form['field_message2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t('Changed date'),
      '#weight' => -1,
      '#markup' => format_date(time(), $created),
    );
  }
```

How do I display the last saved date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code that you need:

```
    if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
    $form['field_message2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t('Changed date'),
      '#weight' => -1,
      '#markup' => format_date($form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->changed->value),
    );
  }
```

Check the [FormStateInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormStateInterface.php/interface/FormStateInterface/8.2.x) interface to see in the methods the [getFormObject()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AgetFormObject/8.2.x) method.

Answer (score 5):

The arguments you are passing a [`format_date()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7.x) are wrong: The second argument is the format used for the date, not another timestamp.

You should code similar to the following one.

```
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
    $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $form['field_message2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t('Changed date'),
      '#weight' => -1,
      '#markup' => format_date($node->getChangedTime(), 'medium'),
    );
  }
```

Even better, you should use the service Drupal provides for formatting dates.

```
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
    $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $form['field_message2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => new \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup('Changed date'),
      '#weight' => -1,
      '#markup' => \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($node->getChangedTime(), 'medium'),
    );
  }
```

Instead of `'medium'`, you can use the default value, or another one you prefer.

Comment: thanks for your answer Kiam, I will take note about this other way.

Comment: Thank you, both of the above worked, but this caused a white screen =new TranslatableMarkup

Comment: I have another question. I want to place another field below the changed date that will display 12 months added on to the changed date? (Add 1 year) This will be called a review date field. The content needs to be reviewed 12 months after the last changed date.

Comment: @paulcap1 That is another question.

Comment: The WSOD is because you need to use the namespace of the class, not just the class name, or add a `use` statement at the beginning of the file.